# Enthalpic Excess - Regular Solution Upon Mixing

Tags: thermodynamics

My professor, in his handout, says the following about this diagram :

> For $\beta>+2$ there are two minima and phase separation occurs driven
>   by unfavourable enthalpic interactions.

I disagree with him partly. For $\Delta_{mix} G/nRT<0$ mixing is spontaneous and hence there solutions would be miscible. Hence at $\beta=2.5$ should we not expect the components to be fully miscible. ?

Following on from this logic; for $\beta=3$ the components are only miscible for $\Delta_{mix} G/nRT<0$ so the maxima represents a phase separation between the two components.

Who is correct ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly does **/beta** represent

Comment: $H^E=nRT\beta x_ax_b$ where $H^E$ is the enthalpic excess and $\beta=w/nRT$ where $w$ is the difference in energy of AB and AA and BB interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your professor is correct.

Long answer: Remember that $\Delta G = G_\text{mixed} - G_\text{unmixed}$. You are correct in saying that for any composition which has $\Delta G < 0$, it is the mixed state that is favorable. However, here mixed does not mean *randomly* mixed, but rather it is a system where the two components interact, whereas in the unmixed state the components A and B are kept in separate containers. Where $\Delta G < 0$, the container containing both A and B has a lower free energy than the two separated systems.

Now take $\beta = 2.5$. No matter what the fraction of A in the mixed container, the mixed system always has a lower free energy than the container containing only A. Imagine that you pour in 50% A and 50% B and mix them. If you kept mixing the container, you would indeed get the free energy at the middle of your graph. If you stopped actively mixing, though, more interesting things would happen: Phase separation. There would be phase X, which is 80% A and 20% B and phase Y, which is 20% A and 80% B (the two minimas in the graph). Neither phase is pure (100% A, say), mind you.

Why should this happen? Imagine your system has 50% phase X and 50% phase Y. Both phase X and phase Y have a free energy lower than that of the phase made up of 50% A and 50% B. If we assume that phase X and phase Y do not interact with each other directly*, then clearly the combination of 50% phase X and 50% phase B has a lower free energy than the system 50% A and 50% B.

For a more general case, there was a recent question (discussion still ongoing)  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112955/flory-huggins-ternary-phase-diagram-with-a-neutral-component/).

* In actuality, they do, and this is called surface tension (or line tension if you have a 2D system). However, taking the thermodynamic limit this energy does not grow as fast as the system (a surface grows $a^2$ whereas the volume goes like $a^3$), and thus can usually be disregarded in the phase diagram.

Comment: http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/~chdms/Teaching/Chemical_Interactions/page_17.htm  There's a similar graph to the one I've posted up for $\beta=3$ and it says there is one phase at the minima whilst there are two phases at the maxima. What does it mean for there to be two phases at the maxima ? Could you illustrate again with percentages ?

Comment: @AriBenCanaan, if you go to the one phase region, i.e. if your system has, say 100 A molecules and 9900 B molecules (1%/99%), there is no way that the system can move towards a lower energy by phase separating. Suppose that locally the system forms the phase X of 100 A, 1330 B so as to have A ratio 0.07. The remaining phase Y will be 100% B, and probably the free energy will not have been lowered. Furthermore, the chemical potential (the slope of the curve) at the two different points will be different, and thus molecules will transfer from one phase to the other.

Comment: To add to this, phase separation can only occur if you have the phase X left of the total composition and the phase Y to the right of it. These points must have the same chemical potential (the derivative must be the same) and you must be able to connect them by a line tangent to the curve at that point. For the symmetric case this means that you will be at the free energy minima. For the asymmetric case it is a bit different (see the link I have in my answer).